# Push notifications with Azure Push Notifications in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For my ASP.NET MVC web application, to send the push notifications among the users I have used SignalR + Firebase.

And I have published my application and hosted it in the Azure service.

As a Database when I developed it I used MS SQL and when publishing it I chose AzureSQL as the database.

The thing is I can't use it because AzureSQL doesn't support the `ENABLE BROKER` hence the push notification isn't working.

So When I googled it, I saw that there is a Service called `Azure Push Notifications`

But I couldn't find a tutorial or example with integrating it with the ASP.NET project.

Is it possible to use Azure Push Notifications for my ASP.NET project? If yes, can anyone share with me the tutorial or something on how to do it?

As far my current project, I did it with the `firebase` and, created `firebase project` and included it in my project to ask to allow notifications when the user logged in, If the user `Allowed` the record saved with the `User Id` and the `token`, And whenever database change is happening, Push notification sends to the user.

So as this can we do it in `Azure push notification`?

Comment: There is Azure SignalR Service - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-signalr-service-a-fully-managed-service-to-add-real-time-functionality/ which achieves what you want.  Azure push notification i have previously used for mobile app push notifications which can be integrated with android and apple mobile apps.

Comment: @SantoshKaranam For this, do we need to ``Enable broker`` from the database side?

Comment: @ Dev Beginner, no it requires azure signal R service, resource to be created - check samples here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core 
https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples